# Is LEFT JOIN with multiple options for the right table demonstrably bad

Tags: mysql, sql

The data:

```
users       username
            ----------
            bob

user_depts  username  | dept_id
            ----------+-----------
            bob       | 1
            bob       | 2
```

The query:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
LEFT JOIN user_depts 
    ON users.username = user_depts.username
```

Is the result defined? We are not using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Is there anywhere that says this syntax is bad?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is exactly the same thing as `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN are equivalent.  The OUTER is basically syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` is a syntactic shortcut for `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, so there should be no difference when using one or the other.